# Maven dependency for <form:form>

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jsp

What is the maven dependency that should be included in order to resolve

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

Error in the jsp file.

```
Cannot find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following spring-webmvc dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: try this one <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `jstl jar` should be in your classpath. If you are using *maven*, add a dependency to jstl in your `pom.xml` using the snippet provided [on this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2). If you are not using *maven*, download the jstl jar from [on this link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) and paste it into your `WEB-INF/lib`.